# Mix ruby code with js.coffee script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I have ajax links on my view, on which I want to check password before they're sent to the actual action, as I am using devise controller, i am restricted to the use of specific password check.
Following is the coffee script I wish to use for the validation.

> .<%= link_to "CANCEL PAYMENT", { :action => "some_action", :info =>
>   n.id },class: "css_class",:remote => true %>

I am using the above link

I am looking for a following kind of code.

```
$("a.css_class").live "click", ->
      password_variable = prompt("Enter password", "password")
      if |ruby-code|current_user.valid_password?(password_variable)|ruby-code|
        true
      else
        alert "You entered wrong password"
        false
```

How'll the ruby code work with coffee script mix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a code for you static asset then it's obvious you won't be able to put some server-side dynamics into it. It'll be converted into a plain JavaScript-snippet and placed into your app's `public` folder.

If you have your view called *.coffee then you already have done all the preparations. The views named this way will be automatically pre-processed with the ERb engine (via `<%= ... %>`):

in **views**/some/thing.coffee:

```
alert "Server's time is <%= Time.now %>"
```

Comment: I think, thenIt'll be better to redirect it to another action first and then call a function from there with render :js => "function();"
what say ?

Comment: @NishutoshSharma I think of making some 'cancel' ajax-action. Then you can to access it via ajax after entering the password at the prompt's field. So, instead of making remote `link_to` you can make `link_to_function` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-link_to_function. It'll ask for the password and issue some non-GET request to cancel an order.

Comment: In Rails 4, I found it necessary to name the file `views/some/thing.coffee.erb` so that the embedded Ruby statements would be processed. This is quite useful for embedding Rails 4's configuration stored in `secrets.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt.

Background:

I am writing an ERP for my company. It uses messages in Spanish, English and Japanese.

I am using coffeescript, haml, scss, NO ERB

So, multilingual messages work fine in all my views, but, I added a .js library for replacing the browser's ugly dropbox with a nice combobox with dropdown list and it uses a hash for holding the messages in local languajes.

So what I did was:

*`_form.html.haml`*

```
:coffeescript
  menssages_for_select2 [
    "#{I18n.t('select.formatNoMatches')}"
    "#{I18n.t('select.formatInputTooShort')}"
    "#{I18n.t('select.formatInputTooLong')}"
    "#{I18n.t('select.formatSelectionTooBig')}"
    "#{I18n.t('select.formatLoadMore')}"
    "#{I18n.t('select.formatSearching')}"
  ]
```

I do this in the view, so I can have access to I18n library. If I try to access the I18n library inside a .js.coffee, it fails

now, in

*`mycode.js.coffee`*

```
@mensajes_select2 = (txt) ->
  $.extend $.fn.select2.defaults,
    formatNoMatches: ->
      txt[0]
    formatInputTooShort: (input, min) ->
      txt[1]
    formatInputTooLong: (input, max) ->
      txt[2]
    formatSelectionTooBig: (limit) ->
      txt[3]
    formatLoadMore: (pageNumber) ->
      txt[4]
    formatSearching: ->
      txt[6]
```